# Download beanstalk instance data

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django server running on Beanstalk, and due to my lack of foresight I didn't choose to use Codecommit at first or migrate away from SQLite. Now every time I deploy my app to the server using `eb deploy`, my data is wipe clean.

Is there any way for me to download the entire code source with data input from users (that means it should also include the updated database) and all for the current instance from the Beanstalk server? If I choose the to download the code from version history, it would just return to me the the zip version of the code I deploy with eb deploy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to download the code for the most recent version of your environment, you can use the command, `eb labs download <environment name>`.

EDIT:

There's no way using the EBCLI to copy the data in your database. You can use the AWSCLI to perform [`aws rds create-db-snapshot`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-snapshot.html). In order to determine the `db-instance-identifier`, you can perform [`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environment-resources.html) against your environment.

EDIT 2:

It is also worth noting that the approach you are using is okay for test and development environments. For production environments, your database should be external to your environment, and something that you manage through RDS yourself, so that you don't lose data when your environment goes down. For more details, please read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html).

Comment: This only download the code I deploy, it doesn't include the change I've made to the database.

Comment: Can you change your original question to reflect that you would also like to archive your database?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to move to a Mysql server on RDS now.